# No Laserscan received for many seconds for navigation?

Tags: navigation, laser, move-base, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I m trying to set up the 2D Navigation Stack. Everything works fine beside of the integration of the laser_scanner.
I set up all the transformations as well as publishing all the needed data as map, odom and laser_scan for autonomous navigation. Nevertheless amcl is always saying this:

> [ WARN] [1488657566.744750961]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1488657566.744665 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.

I have been working with ROS now over 2 years and i dont understand this mistake. My tf_tree (map->odom->base_link->laser_scanner) doesnt show any errors as well as all published topics show the status ok in rviz. If I m using the fake_amcl node everything works fine.
Does anyone know what  I can do ?
The advice that i found here, to set the sim_time to true causes that amcl isnt loading the map.

Thanks for help :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256139/no-laserscan-received-for-many-seconds-for-navigation-?/) by [MP21_R2D2](https://answers.ros.org/users/22346/mp21_r2d2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you publishing your laser data on the topic requested by amcl?
If you type:

```
rostopic info /scan
```

can you see both your laser driver and amcl as publisher/subscriber ?

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0